# Minimal polynomial(Matrix analysis)

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, minimal-polynomials

What are the possible values for a rank of a complex $4\times4$ matrix $A$, knowing that the minimal polynomial $m_A (z) = z^2 - 2z+1$

Comment: Hint : what are the eigenvalues of A ?

Comment: The eigenvalues are 1

Comment: What can you say about A then ?

Comment: Then A has ranks 4, because 0 is not an eigenvalue and we know that 4=r(A)+n(A)?

Answer (score 1):

Since the minimal polynomial is $m_A (z) = z^2 - 2z + 1 = (z - 1)^2$ ,then $p_A (z) = (z - 1)^4$, so the only eigenvalue of $A$ is 1.

Since 0 is is not an eigenvalue of $A$, $A$ is full rank, namely $rank(A) = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

If a square $n\times n$ matrix$~A$ does not have rank$~n$, then $A$ has $0$ as eigenvalue (since $\dim(\ker(A))>0$ by rank nullity), and any annihilating polynomial of $A$ must have $0$ as root, and therefore cannot have a (nonzero) constant term. Since your proposed minimal polynomial does have a nonzero constant term, the rank of $A$ must by $n=4$.